# How change event work on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, onchange

the change function catch only if radio is checked but not when its unchecked. Why? Should it behave like that? When I click the radio button the other is unchanging so the event should fire, right?  Below is the code and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZCX5/1/). Do I do anything wrong?

HTML:

```
Option1 <input type="radio" name="choice" id="op1" checked/>
Option2 <input type="radio" name="choice" id="op2"/>
<br><br>
<span id="sp1">Option1</span><br>
<span id="sp2" style="display: none;">Option2</span>
```

Javascript:

```
var op2 = $('#op2');
var sp1 = $('#sp1');
var sp2 = $('#sp2');

op2.change(function(){
    if(op2.is(':checked')){
        sp1.hide();
        sp2.show();
    }
    else{
        sp2.hide();
        sp1.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your question why doesn't the change event get triggered when an radio input becomes unchecked?

Comment: @j08691 I believe it is, I'm not familiar with this, any words of wisdom?

Comment: @Jasper -nah, I was just thinking of the same basic solution as you came up with (+1 btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector to get it using the name

```
$("input[name='choice']").change(function(){
    if(op2.is(':checked')){
        sp1.hide();
        sp2.show();
    }
    else{
        sp2.hide();
        sp1.show();
    }
});
```

Working sample http://jsbin.com/UPILuCe/1

Comment: Well both yours and Jasper answers working (thank you guys) but you answered first and I liked more the solution with "name".

Answer (score 2):

You can run your event handler when either checkbox changes:

```
$('#op2, #op1').change(...
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TCt82/

Another way to select this would be by element `name` since both checkboxes need to have the same `name` attribute. Selecting by ID will be faster (although you won't be able to see the difference).

**UPADTE**

If anyone knows the exact reason the `change` event does not fire on a checkbox after it's been de-selected, posting it as a comment or answer would be great.